# Capturing from camera with opencv library demands too much power

Tags: c++, opencv, deep-learning, computer-vision

I am working on some eye tracking stuff using the opencv library an haarcascades but I'm trying to optmise a little bit the code beacause at the moment it puts my CPU nearly 200%.
The point is that I figured out how much power demands only taking frames from the camera and puting it in a windows and my surprise was that it puts the CPU to 50%, only with the simplest code like that:

```
#include "opencv2/objdetect/objdetect.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp"

#include <iostream>

//GLOBAL VARIABLES
cv::String cascadePath = "./cascades/haarcascade_eye.xml";
cv::CascadeClassifier cascade;
cv::String windowTitle = "Auto Aim Eye Tracking";
int camNum = 0;

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    cascade.load(cascadePath);
    cv::Mat frame;
    if (cascade.empty())
    {
        std::cout << "Error loading cascade\n";
        return -1;
    }

    cv::namedWindow (windowTitle, CV_WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cv::VideoCapture camera(0);
    if (!camera.isOpened())
    {
        camera.open(1);
        camNum=1;
        if (!camera.isOpened())
        {
            camera.open(2);
            camNum=2;
            if (!camera.isOpened())
            {
                std::cout << "*** UNABLE TO OPEN ANY CAM ***\n*** Press ENTER to exit ***\n";
                std::cin.get();
                return -1;
            }
        }

    }

    while (true){
        camera.read(frame);
        imshow(windowTitle, frame);
        if (cv::waitKey(30) >= 0)
            break;
    }


    std::cout << "*** END OF PROGRAM ***\n*** Press ENTER to exit ***\n";
    std::cin.get();



    return 0;
}
```

I wonder if exists any other way to make this lighter.

Thanks.

P.S: I work in a MacBook Pro 2017.

Comment: You could get smaller resolution images from the camera if possible.  Is it colored? Try making it grayscale, which generally has 1/3  of the bitmap size.  You could also not draw the camera's image to the window as often, since it looks like you're doing it every 30 ms.

Comment: My guess is something is wrong with imshow on your install. This code should run with very little CPU load. I can run very similar code in Python on a Windows install (image size 640x480, 24 bit color) and the CPU load is less than 1%.